# an algorithm that could find a random cycle in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, routes

I am looking for an algorithm that could find a random cycle in a graph from a node while that cycle is traversing around another nodes (area). For example, from the green star on the left of the image, finds a random cycle that goes around the red-star nodes.

[image]

Comment: In your current location pick the next possible node such, that it is closest to the group or red nodes and not yet visited. To find the metric for "closest to red nodes", simply pick the one with minimal "distance sum". On your first corner in the picture for example the one to the right is closer than the one down. You are done when you are back at the starting node, I guess.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the graph is planar?

Comment: Yes, we could assume the graph is planar. It is also directed. It is basically a road network.

Comment: Please define "random". In the example given the path is 14 segments long. If it was 14,000 segments long, is that still a good answer? Does it need to be in relation to the red star nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are looking for a path that is "random", but still fairly close to minimal perimeter around the "red star", you could try this:

First, we need to choose the direction we are going. Let us decide on clockwise, and we start at point `S`.

Second, calculate the shortest path around the red star, including the point `S`. I am not going into details here (e.g. what if it is concave) since this is another question. Also, notice that deciding on `S` is already taking away from the randomness of the algorithm.

While choosing the path, keep 3 parameters (`forward`, `left`, `right`) that present the weight in the random choice of the next move. The difference in the outcome will be largely determined by the handling of theses parameters. You could always keep the weight equal, and then you might never get back to the start point, and even if you do, you don't know that the red star is inside.

To fix this, check the position with the minimal path calculated before.
If you are on it, then `right = 0`. Also, the directions going away from the minimal path could get less and less chances the further you are from it.

Hope this was helpful.